# Working with lists elegantly using python3

Tags: python, list, python-3.6, list-comprehension

I have 2 lists and would like to attain the output as described below, is there an elegant way to do it, the solution that I have works but sure it can be improved, any insights would be helpful,

```
list1 = ['a-g1', 'a-g2', 'a-g3', 'b-g1', 'b-g2', 'b-g3', 'c-g1', 'c-g2', 'c-g3']
list2 = ['a-g1', 'a-g2', 'b-g2', 'c-g1', 'c-g2']

# Expected output
list2 = ['a-g1', 'a-g2', 'c-g1', 'c-g2', 'a-g3', 'c-g3']
```

Code below works, just wondering if it can be enhanced,

```
   if 'g1' in val:
        g2 = val.replace('g1', 'g2')
        if g2 in list2:
            g3 = val.replace('g1', 'g3')
            if g3 not in list2:
                list2.append(g3)
        else:
            list2.remove(val)
    elif 'g2' in val:
        g1 = val.replace('g2', 'g1')
        if g1 in list2:
            g3 = val.replace('g2', 'g3')
            if g3 not in list2:
                list2.append(g3)
        else:
            list2.remove(val)
```

Comment: Can you explain the transformation in words?

Comment: any logic you are following to get the  desired output

Comment: the output i'm trying to achieve is, when list2 contains g1 AND g2 then I need to get g3 from list1 and append to list2. The code snippet that I shared works, all I'm trying to do is finding ways to enhance it. The order does not really matter. Hope this helps

Answer (score -3):

I am not sure how much you care about the order, but what you are doing is essentially

```
list(set(l1).intersection(set(l2)))
```

Comment: I believe that's not what he is doing there. Note that the OP's expected output include `'a-g3'` and `'c-g3'`, which are not part of the intersection of those sets.

Comment: @revliscano You are very likely right, but since he is not telling us what he IS doing, what are we to do? Also, downvoting this is in rather bad taste.

Comment: Fair enough. Nevertheless it wasn't me who downvoted you, I just commented.

Comment: @IgorRivin the output i'm trying to achieve is, when list2 contains g1 AND g2 then I need to get g3 from list1 and append to list2. The code snippet that I shared works, all I'm trying to do is finding ways to enhance it. The order does not really matter. Hope this helps